# Get the closest value for combinations of an array (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm that I can use for combining values in array, to get as close as possible to "another value".

For instance, the number I want to find out what combination that gives the closes result to is 2.5. And my array is `[0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0]`. The combination in this case would be `2.0+0.5`.

2.7 would yield the same combo (2.5 is the closest), while 3.7 would yield `3.0+0.5` and 7.0 would be `3.0+3.0+1.0`.

I've been reading up on different algorithms to create available combinations and such – for instance this one: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/better-way-to-generate-all-combinations However, I'm having difficulties to write a function that allows for the same value to be used multiple times (like my example with 7.0). This makes the number of combinations quite large.

Anyone having a good example tucked away? Or have any pointers to give?

**EDIT**
@zkar told me about the "knapsack problem". I may add that for my example, the sought after value are in a specified range (1.0 and 10.0) – which limits the the combinations somewhat.

Comment: Look at this [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)
Seems to me that this is what you should read.

Comment: While I agree that this might fall under the "Knapsack Problem", there's still the difference that I only have one type of value to worry about (let's say the weight in the Wikipedia-example), not two.

Comment: If you want to find closest in array than you can push number than sort it and then take second and previous number of that number and try to use Math.round or try something like this ;)

Comment: Please, check if this suits: http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/p8xZM/5/ All three provided examples are valid.

Comment: I assume you also want the smallest number of elements? A simple algorithm would give `0.5+0.5+0.5+0.5+0.5` for 2.5. (Although @fedosov's algorithm takes care of that.)

Comment: Also, does the sum have to be smaller than the target number? For example if the target is 2.4, should the answer be `2.0` or `2.0+0.5`?

Comment: @fedosov – thank you, excellent solution, running tests right now, and it seems to work out! Juhana, yepp smallest number of elements it is. However, it would be even better if it would be solvable with the absolute closest combination – no matter if it is bigger or smaller.

Comment: @fedosov: Your simple algorithm doesn't work for `[0.5, 1.3]` as input, searching for `2.0`

Comment: perhaps you could use the combinations approach together with fedosov's and have your function pick the closest combination

Comment: @fedosov Your solutions seems to work out! Please post an answer so I can check it off. Also, do have any idea how to edit your solution so that the method always chose the closest combination that is bigger, instead of smaller? Would be awesome =)

Comment: @Marcus i posted an answer with proposed edits.

Comment: Of the Combinatorial search problems, this most closely resembles the SubsetSum problem (here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).  However, it is ***Not*** a Combinatorial search problem,  IIRC it's a PowerSet search problem, and they're a bit trickier to get exact answers (and also have higher computational complexity).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a mixture of [Coin Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) and [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

**If Coins are used only Once:**

Given a set of values S, n = |S|, m: value to approximate

```
DEFINE BEST = { }
DEFINE SUM = 0
DEFINE K = 0

WHILE S IS NOT EMPTY DO
    K = K + 1
    FIND MIN { Si : |(SUM+Si) - m| is minimal }
    ADD TUPLE < Si, |(SUM+Si) - m|, K > to BEST
    SUM = SUM + Si
    REMOVE Si from S
END-FOR

RETURN BEST
```

This algorithm runs in Time: O(|S|<sup>2</sup>) ~ O(n<sup>2</sup>)

The Set BEST will have n solutions, for each K: 1..n

for K: you have the optimal choice at that stage

to find the complete solution:

```
GIVEN BEST = { < COIN:X, DISTANCE:Y, DEGREE:K > }
DEFINE SOLUTION = { }
Y" = MINIMUM Y IN BESTi.Y for i: 1..n
KEEP ADDING BESTj.X to SOLUTION UNTILL BESTj.Y = Y" FOR j: 1..n
```

**If Coins can be re-used:**

```
DEFINE SOLUTION = { }
DEFINE SUM = 0
LESS = { Si : Si < m }
SORT LESS IN DESCENDING ORDER
FOR Li in LESS DO
    WHILE (SUM+Li) <= m DO
        SUM = SUM + Li
        ADD Li TO SOLUTION
    END-WHILE

    IF SUM = m THEN BREAK-FOR
END-FOR
RETURN SOLUTION
```

In JavaScript:

```
function coinProblem (var coins, var value)
{
    var solution = new Array();
    var sum = 0;
    var less = new Array();

    for (var i in coins)
        if (i <= value)
            less.push(i);

    // sort in descending order
    less.sort();
    less.reverse();

    for (var i in less)
    {
        while ((sum+i) <= value)
        {
            solution.push(i);
            sum = sum + i;
        }

        if (sum == value) break;
    }

    return solution;
}
```

Comment: I don't completely grok your pseudo-code conventions,  In particular, how should the line `FIND MIN { Si : |(SUM+Si) - m| is minimal }` be read?

Comment: Hmm, if I read this correctly, isn't it just a Greedy heuristic?  It won't necessarily return the exact answer all of the time would it?

Comment: As with fedesov's solution, if I pass `S={0.4,1.0}, m=0.8` I think that your algorithm returns `{1.0}` instead of the correct `{0.4,0.4}`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung `FIND MIN { Si : |(SUM+Si) - m| is minimal }` is: Find Si that comes with minimum |(SUM+Si) - m| .. Also my solution is Dynamic Programming with Greedy Heuristic

Comment: @RBarryYoung if the coins can be re-used, then the algorithm will be different .. let me fix my solution

Comment: Well it is Heuristic (which is not what was asked for), but I do not see any Dynamic Programming.

Comment: The second algorithm is Greedy, and it is optimal since it maximize fitting

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple algorithm ([JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/p8xZM/15/)):

```
/**
 * @param src {Array} List of available values
 * @param val {Number} Target value
 * @returns {Array}
 */
function get_combinations(src, val)
{
    var result = [];
    var source = src.slice();
    source.sort();

    while (val > 0)
    {
        for (var i = source.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (source[i] <= val || i == 0)
            {
                val = val - source[i];
                result.push(source[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: For parameters `src={0.4,1.0}, val=0.8` the return answer should be `{0.4,0.4}`, but it looks like this algorithm returns `{1.0}` instead.

Comment: Efter running some more tests, I am getting some strange results in some cases. for instance with `src = [0.5, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0]` and `val = 1.44` should give `result = [1.5]`. Instead I get `result = [1.25, 0.5]`. This sure is tricky =) Looking at @khaleds solution to see if I can apply some of it to yours.

Comment: For source = 2, 3 and val = 4 this returns 3, but should be 2+2=4